# Xcode Beta "Verifying Xcode.app"

Tags: macos, xcode

I just installed Xcode beta, and when trying to open it, it stays on "Verifying Xcode.app" and does not proceed. Why is that? I have the latest OS X mavericks.

Comment: You may try to get rid of extended attributes with: `xattr -cr /path/to/Xcode.app`

Answer (score 9):

Open terminal and run below commands

```
cd /Applications
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Xcode.app
```

This will bypass Gatekeeper in OS X and launch Xcode quickly.

Comment: This doesn't work for me as I don't have Xcode.app to begin with. I get: xattr: No such file: Xcode.app

Answer (score 0):

You said you are stuck with Xcode beta.
Then the command will be

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Xcode\ Beta.app`

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a global switch for the verifying in `com.apple.LaunchService`.

```
❯ defaults read com.apple.LaunchServices{
    LSQuarantine = 1;
}

❯ defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO

❯ defaults read com.apple.LaunchServices
{
    LSQuarantine = 0;
}
```

It should take effect after a rebooting.